# Macro as macro parameter expansion not working

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Why does the following minimal example not work?

```
static inline int test_1(int x) { return x; }
#define TEST(a, ...) test_##a(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ONE 1
void temp() {
    TEST(1, 5); // OK
    TEST(ONE, 5); // error: use of undeclared identifier 'test_ONE'
}
```

From my understanding, macros inside macros should work as long as they are not recursive.

Comment: You're missing an extra level of indirection: `#define CONCAT(a, b) a##b \n #define TEST(a, ...) CONCAT(test_,a)(__VA_ARGS__)`, but I don't know *why* it's necessary.

Comment: `test_##a` makes that `test_ONE` is evaluated, not `ONE`

Comment: (See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889867/macro-concatenation-using-compiler-define)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `-E` option you can see [what your code looks like](https://godbolt.org/g/ERtSsA) after the pre-processor stage.

Macros are expanded in multiple passes and have their own order of precedence.

In this case `TEST(ONE,5)` is expanding directly to `test_ONE(5)`.

If you add a single layer ([or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508666/4499969)) of indirection you can cause `ONE` to expand before the `##` operator is seen.

```
#define TEST_I(a,...)test_##a(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TEST(a, ...) TEST_I(a,__VA_ARGS__)
```

As on the first pass `TEST(ONE,5)` is expanded into `TEST_I(ONE,5)` and then `TEST_I(1,5)`, and on second pass this becomes `test_1(5)`.

The `TEST_I` isn't expanded on the first pass though because it is generated by the expansion of `TEST` whereas the `ONE` was already present.